# print only bootstrap modal in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to print bootstrap modal but it prints also the screen behind and not only the modal.
Is there a way to do it?
Thanks in advance!

What i did is simply using `window.print()` inside the modal.

Comment: You could use CSS to expand modal to full size etc by using `@media print`.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.